How to get the path of s3 file while loading into the physical table in redshift?
I am getting the path of the s3 files from external table using :
create or replace view raw_view as select *,"$path" as sourcefilename from raw_external_table WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING;

Now I want the sourcefilename also in the physical tables using the copy command from redshift.
I cannot use this:
COPY staging_table (cola, colb, colc, cold)
FROM 's3://your-bucket-name/path/to/files/'
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/YourRedshiftRole' -- Replace with your IAM role ARN
DELIMITER '|' -- Adjust delimiter as per your file format
IGNOREHEADER 1 -- If your files have a header row
REMOVEQUOTES -- If your data is enclosed in quotes
CSV; -- If your files are in CSV format

-- Update the sourcefilename column in the staging table with the S3 file path
UPDATE staging_table
SET sourcefilename = 's3://your-bucket-name/path/to/files/';

Because I m loading from a directory and there are many files in the directory. Any approaches to get the s3 filenames in the physical tables.

No, you would need to add a value into the each record in the files themselves to identify the data, or load them in batches maybe using manifest files to know what files are coming in for that batch.
